# ATxmega: reading a register with TWI/I²C

Tags: integrated-circuit, atmel, twi, atxmega

I am trying to read a register value from the *Bosch BMA280* with the *ATxmega*. But I cannot make it work. The code I tried looks like this:

```
TWI.MASTER.ADDR = (BMA280_SLAVE_ADDRESS << 1) | 0;      // writing mode
while(!(TWI.MASTER.STATUS & TWI_MASTER_WIF_bm));

TWI.MASTER.DATA = reg_address;                          // send Register address
while(!(TWI.MASTER.STATUS & TWI_MASTER_WIF_bm));

TWI.MASTER.ADDR = (BMA280_SLAVE_ADDRESS << 1) | 1;      // reading mode
while(!(TWI.MASTER.STATUS & TWI_MASTER_RIF_bm));

data = TWI.MASTER.DATA;                                 // get data
TWI.MASTER.CTRLC = TWI_MASTER_CMD_STOP_gc;              // send stop bit
```

When changing to reading mode, the RIF flag is never set

Answer (score 1):

You are not waiting for TWI transfer to complete. If you do not want to use interrupt-driven code, you have to wait for appropriate flag in `TWI.MASTER.STATUS` being set after each write to `ADDR` and `CTRLC` registers.

These flags are `WIF` and `RIF` bits in `STATUS` register (or you can use `CLKHOLD` bit which should be logical or of these two flags). See, for example, [AVR XMEGA AU manual](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-8331-8-and-16-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-XMEGA-AU_Manual.pdf), page 265 for details.

When `ADDR` is written, either `WIF` or `RIF` flag will be set after completion (or on error). `RIF` is set in case slave was addressed in read mode and one byte was already received then. `WIF` in all other cases. See pg. 259 in the manual.

In your case (addressing slave in write mode) `WIF` will be set. You should check that neither `RXACK`, `BUSERR` nor `ARBLOST` bit in `STATUS` register is set. If all are zero slave have acknowledged its address and you can send data.

Write `DATA` register and wait for `WIF` flag. You should check the `RXACK` bit in `STATUS` register too when flag is set (bit is zero if slave acknowledged this databyte).

For repeated start just write `ADDR` register with new value. Writing the `CTRLC` reg. is not necessary and it results in one extra addressing with original address you do not want.

When slave is addressed in read mode (and it acknowledges the address), AVR will automatically receive first data byte (except when `QCEN` bit in `CTRLB` is set), so you have your a databyte ready when `RIF` flag is set. (But be prepared to see `WIF` flag instead of `RIF` too -- it happens in case of any error during addressing.)

Reading `DATA` register does not affect TWI state machine nor flags (assuming `SMEN` bit of `CTRLB` register is not set; note that datasheet is quite unclear on this), so you can read databyte first and issue STOP command (or `BYTEREC` command in case you want read more) after.

Comment: I am not sure which flag I shall check.
The flags I tried are never set (Debugger remains in the while Loops)

Comment: TWI.MASTER.STATUS |= TWI_MASTER_BUSSTATE_IDLE_gc;       // Force TWI bus into idle mode.
  TWI.MASTER.ADDR = (BMA280_SLAVE_ADDRESS << 1) | 0;      // writing mode

  while((TWI.MASTER.STATUS & 0x10) != 0x10);    // wait for ACK
  TWI.MASTER.DATA = 0x03;                          // send Register address
  TWI.MASTER.CTRLC = TWI_MASTER_CMD_REPSTART_gc;          // send repeated start
  while((TWI.MASTER.STATUS & 0x40) != 0x40);    // wait for write interrupt flag`

Comment: TWI.MASTER.ADDR = (BMA280_SLAVE_ADDRESS << 1) | 1;      // reading mode
  while((TWI.MASTER.STATUS & 0x10) != 0x10);    // wait for ACK

  TWI.MASTER.CTRLC = TWI_MASTER_CMD_STOP_gc;              // send stop bit
  while((TWI.MASTER.STATUS & 0x80) != 0x80);    // wait for read interrupt flag
  data = TWI.MASTER.DATA;                                 // get data

Comment: sorry, the code cannot be formatted well...
I am checking the ACK flag after setting the Slave Address + R/W, the WIF after writing and RIF after reading

Comment: I have extended my answer with description how you should work with flags and TWI. The datasheet is not so easy to understand (and partially misleading), but I recommend you to read it anyway. The RXACK bit is not completion flag. Wait for RIF and WIF! (And note that zero RXACK bit means "acknowledged", that is successful transfer.)

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help. But the issue remains, that the RIF flag is never set after changing to reading mode

Comment: And write does work for you? Is WIF flag set after addressing in read mode? What is the value of complete STATUS reg.? Maybe some error on physical layer or BMA280 is not responding to the address for any reason? Try to provide more info (maybe edit your question, so you can format it in more readable form).

Comment: The sensor worked fine with another ASIC. When I issue the read command, the WIF and ARBLOST flags are enabled, plus the master is in BUSY busstate

Comment: I've tried it with the same code again. This time, when changing to reading mode, no flags are enabled and the busstate remains in BUSY state. (I've edited my question with the updated code)